# I dont understand why my Java code isnt reading IX as 9 but is reading LIX as 59

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, roman-numerals

I am trying to create some code to read roman numerals and turn them into an integer. the issue im having is the 9s and 4s. I am able to get it to read if the 9 or 4 is inside a number (I.E LIV is 54 and LXI is 59) but by its self (IV and IX) it only reads 6 and 11.
here is my code:

```
public static void RomantoInt(String s) {
    HashMap<Character, Integer> RomanNums = new HashMap<>();
    int count = 0;

    RomanNums.put('I', 1);
    RomanNums.put('V', 5);
    RomanNums.put('X', 10);
    RomanNums.put('L', 50);
    RomanNums.put('C', 100);
    RomanNums.put('D', 500);
    RomanNums.put('M', 1000);


    LinkedList<Character> UserInput = new LinkedList<>();

    //Adds Each numeral to the Array
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char userint = s.charAt(i);
        UserInput.add(userint);
    }

    //loop through the array backwards and adds up the count.
           for(int j =UserInput.toArray().length -1; j> -1 ; j--) {
               int grab = RomanNums.get(UserInput.get(j));
               count += grab;

   // Checks for 4s and 9s.

               if(grab == RomanNums.get('X') && (j - 1) == RomanNums.get('I')) {
                   count -= 2;
               }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: 1) Going backwards through the string is the same as going forwards 2) don't use `UserImput`, just do `grab = RomanNums.get(s.charAt(i)` (in the future, if you want to convert a String to a collection, just do `.split('')`) 3) instead of keeping track of which combinations of values mean subtraction, you can subtract when a smaller value (e.g. `I`) is between two bigger ones(e.g. `XIX`). You'll need to save the previous value as a new variable to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing `j - 1` -- which is a position in a string -- to the value of a roman numeral does not seem to make any sense.

Specifically, it only works when the roman 'I' is the second character, exactly.

What you really want to be testing is whether the character at the (j-1)'th position is 'I'.

The correct formulation should be something like

```
if (grab == RomanNums.get('X') &&
    j > 0 &&
    UserInput.get(j-1) == 'I') ...
```

Comment: sorry that was becasue I assumed that the reason it wasnt reading the I for IV or IX was because of its 0th position in the array. but I think I understand where you are coming from. the reason I used j -1 was because Im trying to get the next element in the loop.

Comment: I guess my question would be how would I test the (J-1)th position is 'I' thats what I thought I was doing.

Comment: `j > 0 && UserInput.get(j-1) == 'I'`  (note check that j-1 is a legal index  before you try and get it).

Comment: Thank you. See I knew I had to check for zero thats why initially the title mentioned zero but I didnt know where I should check for it. Thank you so much

Comment: I edited the answer to make my last comment part of the answer, in case the comments vanish.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution for leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/roman-to-integer/

You have the right idea about reading the input backwards and one loop should be enough to get the job done.

All you need to do is account for the cases when you have to subtract the roman numeral, and you can do that by keeping track of the previous roman numeral for comparison.

For example when input string is: "IX"

We start at 'X' in the first iteration and since previous is equal to '?' we just add 10 and set previous to 'X'. Now when we attempt to sum up 'I' in the next iteration, we look at previous and notice that it is an 'X' and instead of adding 1 to the running sum , we should subtract 1. The total should be 9.

```
public int romanToInt(String s) {
        int sum = 0;
        char prev = '?';
        
        for(int i = s.length()-1;i >= 0;i--)    {
            
            switch(s.charAt(i))    {
                case 'I'    : sum += prev == 'V' || prev == 'X' ? -1 : 1;
                    break;
                case 'V'    : sum += 5;
                    break;
                case 'X'    : sum += prev == 'L' || prev == 'C' ? -10 : 10;
                    break;
                case 'L'    : sum += 50;
                    break;
                case 'C'    : sum += prev == 'D' || prev == 'M' ? -100 : 100;
                    break;
                case 'D'    : sum += 500;
                    break;
                case 'M'    : sum += 1000;
                    break;
                default     : 
                    break;
            }
            prev = s.charAt(i);
        }
        return sum;        
    }
```

```
Time complexity is O(n) - Iterated the length of the input string
Space complexity is O(1) - No additional data structure was needed
```

Comment: Going backwards doesn't seem to change anything. Can share my solution if you're curious